# How to get Set 5 rows from dataset in every PostBack in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datatable, dataset, datarow

Help me to sort the below issue.

I have a Dataset and the Dataset has Tables with 'n' number of rows.

I want to display first 5 rows from the table in dataset.

My Page will refresh every 1 minutes.So Whenever my pages is refreshing I need to display the next 5 rows from the dataset.

For Example
 If my dataset has 15 rows.

When loading the page for first time it should display/get only first 5 rows (1 to 5)from the dataset.

Wehn the page postback/refresh it should dispaly second set of 5 rows (6 to 10) from the dataset.

And again when the page postback it should dispaly thirdset of 5 rows (11 to 15) from the dataset.

Note:I am not using GridView in my webPage. 
I am using dynamic controls to populate the data's from the dataset.

Thanks,

David

Comment: if u need db code pls mension...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone the original DataTable, and copy whatever rows you want to the cloned DataTable.

```
private DataTable CopyDataTable(DataTable dt, int index)
{
    DataTable cloneDT = dt.Clone(); // Clone DataTable Structure

    for (int i = index, j = index + 5; i < j; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
        cloneDT.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
    }

    return cloneDT;
}
```

You can invoke the method like this:

```
GridView1.Datasource  = CopyDataTable(dt, 0); // create new DataTable, with rows 0-4
GridView1.DataBind();

GridView1.Datasource  = CopyDataTable(dt, 5); // create new DataTable, with rows 5-9
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a hiddentfield and set the value as 1. then on pageload inside ispostback=true statement just increment the value of hiddenfield. then pass the value of hiddenfield into the db.

sample code...

```
    if (isPostBack){
hiddentFieldForTimeCount.value= (int)hiddentFieldForTimeCount.value+1;

}

function CallDB(){
DataTable tbl=function callDB(hiddentFieldForTimeCount.value);
DataBind(tbl);
}
```

based on the hiddenfield value you can pick the data from database.